# Center logo images within row on shopify page, with css / html?

Tags: html, css, shopify

I am making a grid of logos for a client's site. I am wondering how to make them centered within the grids in rows and columns. I have for css:

```
.center-block {
display: block;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

let me know if any solutions exist.

Comment: It's very very unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the logo centered horizontally you can do something like this and replace .center-me with your class for the element you want centered.

if it's a block element do this.

```
.center-me {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

if it's inline (text or links) do this

```
.center-me {
  text-align: center;
}
```